# why print dialog is not opened in IE when printing a dive content using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to print a dive content using javascript and jquery and using following code:

```
 n = window.open('M80Print.aspx', '_blank', 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,height=400px,width=640px');
          n.document.write($('#<%=Print.ClientID %>').html());
          n.print();
```

It works in Fire Fox and Chrome but print dialog is not opened in IE.
I use IE8. wht to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE requires you to *open* the document before writing to it then *close* it before printing:

```
n.document.open();
n.document.write($('#<%=Print.ClientID %>').html());
n.document.close();
n.print();
```

Tested for IE9 should work with IE8 as well.

Comment: It dowsn't work in any browsers. Fire fox, IE8 and chrome. Window is closes when print dialog opened

Comment: See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/REJ6y/1/) - click the Print button. Window does not get closed so it's something else in your code - please post more code and we'll see.

Comment: This is all of my code: 
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv() {
            n = window.open('M80Print.aspx', '_blank', 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,height=400px,width=640px');

            n.document.write($('#<%=Print.ClientID %>').html());
            n.close();
            n.print();
</script>`

Comment: You are closing the window before trying to print it, how you expect it to stay open?? Anyway, move `n.close();` to be **after** `n.print();`. You are also missing closing bracket for the function..

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now it works in all browsers.This is my code:
`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function printDiv() {
            n = window.open('M80Print.aspx', '_blank', 'status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,height=400px,width=640px');
            n.document.open();
            n.document.write($('#<%=Print.ClientID %>').html());
            n.document.close();
            n.print();
        }
    </script>`